# Noise Spike removal Magnetometer C#

Tags: c#, sensors, noise, magnetometer

I have a large set of data gathered by by reading the registers of Magnetometer.

Data is like this

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,-120,4,8,8,8,8,8,8,13,113,13,13,13,13
```

How can i remove -120 and 113 in the above data by using some filter in C#.(Median Filter, etc)

Comment: You are right. Median filter is good for this case. What is the problem? 
Add values to filter step by step and for each step you get filtered value. Set window of median filter 3 or 5, i supose that would be enough